# How can i center vertically and horizontally the content of the content section?

Tags: css

i want to certer the content of the content section, but when i tried to do that its centering in related of the page, i dont want that, this is my attempt:

```css
.sideBar {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  background: aqua;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: yellow;
}

.inner {
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
```

```html
<h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="sideBar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">ANALYTICS</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="inner">content</div

  </div>
</div>
```

i dont know what is the wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because .inner is positioned absolutely, it is not relative to .content
try:

```css
.sideBar {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  background: aqua;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.inner {

  }
```

```html
<h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="sideBar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">ANALYTICS</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="inner">content</div

  </div>
</div>
```

Now whenever you change the size of .content, .inner should be placed in the center.

#### When you make an element `display: flex` and add `justify-content: center` and `align-items: center`, children should be placed in the center.

Comment: i wanted to center vertically and horizontally

Comment: it should once you change the height of .content since there is no height given